# How to add separate strings to array from button click and delete strings from array with a different button click?

Tags: java

I am wondering how to add strings to an array from a button click, this is what I have so far but only one text value is written to the array the rest are empty

```
private void addTeamButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
   String teamArray []=new String[5];

teamArray[0]= addTeamText.getText();
addTeamText.setText("");
teamArray[1]= addTeamText.getText();
addTeamText.setText("");
teamArray[2]= addTeamText.getText();
addTeamText.setText("");
teamArray[3]= addTeamText.getText();
addTeamText.setText("");
teamArray[4]= addTeamText.getText();
```

What I want to do is add multiple teams to a list and then be able to delete them from the array with a button called say "deleteTeamButton" if anybody has any pointers on how to implement this i would be very grateful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you just said, you only need to initialize an array list and add items in your on click function.

```
ArrayList<String> Teams = new ArrayList<>();

private void addTeamButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
String Team = addTeamText.getText(); 
System.out.println (Team);
Teams.add(Team);
addTeamText.setText("");
```

}

The same for the function that deletes items. You can look for ArrayList documentation for the deletion process.